# How to push table structure from local PostgreSQL database to Heroku database without data

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have used this command to push data into Heroku database from my local PostgreSQL database:

```
heroku pg:push <localdatabaseurl> <herokudatabaseurl> --app <APP>
```

The issue is this code pushes the table structure along side with data.

I want to only push table structure without pushing data.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [`pg:push -—exclude-table-data`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-push-source-target) option.

Or create a local database with schema only:

[`pg_dump —-schema-only`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

Then push to Heroku.